# Angular Js : {{message}} is not replaced by some text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my very simple example where I am trying to implement controller.

{{8/2}} is giving correct output i.e. `4` but  {{message}} remains same.

It should be replaced by some value e.g. `First Controller`

I downloaded the angular js from `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js`

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>{{8/2}}</h1>
  <div ng-controller="HomeController">
      {{message}} 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Script.js

```
var HomeController = function($scope) {

  $scope.message = "First Controller";

};
```

Comment: can you show your script.js ?

Comment: Expose all your HomeController implementation please

Comment: u  have not added the module definition ng-app="someApp" , and use this in creating your module and controller

Comment: This works as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ucbcj5ay/ .Do you have any js errors?

Comment: @ngLover and @felipekm : Please check it here ``http://plnkr.co/edit/13CYSM2kQHVR0EN6ZiTq?p=preview``

Comment: @Amir : Please check http://plnkr.co/edit/13CYSM2kQHVR0EN6ZiTq?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I downloaded the angular js from
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js

Well angularjs version 1.4x does not support raw functions controllers to be used as controllers. change the angularjs version to 1.2.x OR use `angular.module('someName').controller()` syntax to make it work.

Here's the same [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/w6KgGvaUInOETsAKgKBn?p=preview) you shared(with angularjs 1.2.8)

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RiA8t2oU8RR5WVmiETcn) with angular.module() syntax

Answer (score 1):

Update your html from

```
<html ng-app>
```

to

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Update your script.js to

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("HomeController", function($scope){
    $scope.message = "First Controller";

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your Script.js with this

```
var ng_app = angular.module('ng_app',[]);
ng_app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "First Controller";
}]);
```

edit `ng-app` in your html to `ng-app='ng_app'`

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with your angular version If you will use a older version then it works fine

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app>
{{8/7}}
 <div  ng-controller="HomeController">
{{message}}
</body>
</html>
<script >
// Code goes here


 var HomeController = function($scope) {

  $scope.message = "First Controller";

};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using old syntax that is no longer supported.Instead of defining controller as `var`. Add `ng-app="app"`, then create a module

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);
```

Now define your controller -

```
myApp.controller("HomeController",function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello";
});
```